# Ionic Framework cmd.exe Error: ENOENT no such file or directory

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, filenotfoundexception

> ***EDIT:*** My Android SDK toold are installed in C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

I have an ionic project that I'm trying to install and export as apk to test. I already have a www folder which I will replace.

I opened cmd.exe as administrator and run the command:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Then I install my project by: (It is located in C:\Windows\System32\testapp )

```
ionic start testapp blank
```

I cd into my app by:

```
cd testapp
```

When I try to install android I get the following error:

```
 ionic platform add android
```

[image]

As you can see this isn't a path problem and I have Android Studio SDK installed.

What could be causing this? It doesn't even work for blank apps.

Comment: firstly, its a bad idea to install stuff in system32 dir. Secondly, doesn't look like youre actually inside your `testapp` directory!

Comment: @mani thanks, I will move the installation elsewhere, in the mean time I ran the same thing from the inside. Please find the updated screenshot